# map dependend xarray coordinates

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray with dimensions in x,y which also has coordinates in lat,lon. Since these are shifted grids the lat and lon are both dependend on x,y. I want to convert my coordinate system to lat, lon but I am unsure how to achieve this.

I have tried to assign different coordinates, or to stack and unstack the dimensions, but unfortunatly this is not really getting me closer to my solution.

Comment: People may be more willing to help if you are able to provide a workable example of your code.

Comment: You can’t just force data in a cartographic projection to have regular lat/lon dimensions. You need to regrid your data through interpolation or some other means to a new grid. Check out the xESMF package for tools for doing this

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDelgado this was exactly the information that I needed! Regredding my data with xESMF was indeed what was needed.